# Scrolling through several rows in a database and displaying each one every few seconds

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am working on a PHP project and I am looking for a bit of advise as I am not sure if what I am thinking is the best way to implement it.

What I need is to show some news bulletins regarding my site that are retrieved from a database. I then want to display each row every few seconds, e.g. it displays row 1, waits 5 seconds, then displays row 2, waits 5 seconds then shows row etc.

I'm not sure how best to implement it. Should I have a javascript function that does an ajax post `($.post)` to query the database, and return the results in a json, and then keep looping through every x seconds to display the next row. Or keep querying the database to get the next record to show or is there a better method to implement this.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: If there are less than say, 20 records being cycled at a time, i'd go with querying the database once.

Comment: How many would be cycled through at any given time, and do you need it to automatically update if there's a new record in the database?  Is it only the most recent 10 or 15 news bulletins?  All the bulletins for the last five days?  What are we looking at here?

Comment: It would vary the number of bulletins, 10 would prob be max. The bulletins will auto turn on/off dependent on start/end time within the database. Which is why I was thinking I would prob need to query the database for each row I want to display